# Empty catch block

Tags: c#, try-catch

There is a library (which I don't control) containing a function named **Inner** that raises exceptions of type **StupidException**. I'm writing a function named **Outer** that calls **Inner**. I can't tell in advance when a **StupidException** will be raised, and I can't handle it in any reasonable way. I don't want callers of my function **Outer** to ever see a **StupidException** -- I'm going to communicate the situation to them by returning null from **Outer**, instead (for several reasons). So, it seems to me that the most reasonable code is:

```
public thing Outer()
{
  thing result = null;
  try
  {
     result = Inner();
  }
  catch(StupidException ex)
  {
     // do nothing
  }
  return result;
}
```

I've read stern warnings about how an empty catch block is evil because it "swallows" the exception. Swallowing the exception is exactly what I want to do, here, actually, but the empty catch block still doesn't feel right, to me. Is there a better way?

Comment: Just because you don't want your callers to see the exception doesn't mean that _you_ shouldn't see the exception and log it.

Comment: But how does your `Outer` consumer now know it passed invalid arguments, if you swallow _all_ exceptions? Now he'll just think the query didn't return any results.

Comment: @CodeCaster -- there aren't any arguments, but I see your point. I've modified the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If that would make you feel more comfortable you could return from the catch block so that it doesn't look empty:

```
public thing Outer()
{
    try
    {
        return Inner();
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

If the intent is to swallow exceptions that this is alright. You might just want to verify the type of exceptions that this inner function could throw in order to catch only them instead of catching all exceptions. For example you could contact the authors of this code in order to ask them about the type of exception their code could throw and then target those exceptions only.

Comment: You're right -- I shouldn't be catching all exceptions indiscriminately. I only want to communicate one particular kind of exception via a null return from Outer. I clarified this in the question.

Comment: Alright, then you should catch only `StupidException` and not all exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You need list of all expected exceptions, you may get from Inner and catch only these. That is the correct solution.

Comment: It would be wonderful if I had such a list, but I don't. I know of only one type of exception that's thrown by Inner, and that's the one I want to communicate as a null return to callers of Outer.

Comment: If it is only one exception, then your problem is easy.